# update neighbors in 2d Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, count, 2d

I am using a 2D array to count its neighbors and update the current cell given its neighbor count.My count method  (lifeCount= countAlive(copy,i,k)) is looking at the updated array instead of the original. I need it to keep looking at the original instead of the copy. I'd appreciate if anyone can help.

```
public static void UpdateMatrix(boolean original[][]) {


    int lifeCount;
    boolean[][] copy = (boolean[][]) original.clone(); //copy array
    for (int i = 1; i < original.length - 1; i++) {

        for (int k = 1; k < original[i].length - 1; k++) {


            lifeCount= countAlive(copy,i,k);
            System.out.println(lifeCount);

            if (original[i][k] == true) {

                if (lifeCount < 3 || lifeCount > 8) {
                    copy[i][k] = false;
                }
            }


            if (original[i][k] == false) {

                if (lifeCount >= 3 && lifeCount <= 8) {

                    copy[i][k] = true;

                }

            }



        } /// matrix has updated

    }


}// end findNeighborg
```

Comment: I dont really understand your question, but i will try. So you want your algorithm instead of looking at your updated (copied grid) at your originall grid right ?

Comment: Do you need help implementing the `countAlive()` method? One thing is for sure: You need to pass `original` to it instead of `copy`.

Comment: public static int countAlive(boolean d[][], int i, int k) {
 int alive = 0;
for (int row = 0; row <= 2; row++) {   top row
                  if (d[i - 1][k - 1 + row]==true) {
                alive++;
            }
        }
    for (int row = 0; row <= 2; row++) {  //mid row

          if (d [i - 0][k - 1 + row] == true) {
                alive++;}

        if (d[i][k]) {
            alive -= 1;
  for (int row = 0; row <= 2; row++) {   //bottom row

            if (d[i + 1][k - 1 + row]==true) {
                alive++;
            }
        }
        return alive;
    }

Comment: Here is my counting method. Sorry I am new to this site.